# Ember Addon: Forcing overriting a file

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I created a ember addon that installs the ember-cli-eslint addon when calling the afterInstall hook however when the plugin installs I always get prompted to if I want to override the .eslintrc files where I have to manually enter yes. Is there a way to force to always to override the files?

```
installing ember-cli-eslint
[?] Overwrite .eslintrc? No, skip
[?] Overwrite tests\.eslintrc? No, skip
skip .eslintrc
skip tests\.eslintrc
```

Answer (score 1):

Someone taught me this:

```
$ yes | ember install plugin-name
```

`yes` is a UNIX command that continually outputs yes, and `|` "pipes" it into the program, effectively answering yes every time `ember install` asks the user a question.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/10864505)

Comment: @CalebKleveter it doesn't?

Comment: The format makes it more of a comment then an answer. If you expand on it more, then it would qualify more as an answer.

Comment: @CalebKleveter I've tried explaining the different components of the solution and the interaction, does it look sufficient?